# Simple graphics interactivity

Tags: java, graphics

I am trying to write a GraphicsProgram that allows the user to draw lines on the canvas. Pressing the mouse button sets the starting point for the line. Dragging the mouse moves the other endpoint around as the drag proceeds. Releasing the mouse fixes the line in its current position and gets ready to start a new line.

Can someone explain why when I run the code the lines are not able to be displayed, and what about the correct code, which I have also attached, makes it preferable.

My code:`

```
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import acm.graphics.*;

public class DrawLines extends GraphicsProgram{

public void init(){
    addMouseListeners();
    line=new GLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    x1=e.getX();
    y1=e.getY();
}
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    x2=e.getX();
    y2=e.getY();
    add(line);
}

private GLine line;
private int x1;
private int y1;
private int x2;
private int y2;
```

}

Correct code:

```
import acm.graphics.*; 
import acm.program.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 

/** This class allows users to drag lines on the canvas */ 
public class RubberBanding extends GraphicsProgram { 
   public void run() { 
      addMouseListeners(); 
   } 

/** Called on mouse press to create a new line */ 
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 
      double x = e.getX(); 
      double y = e.getY(); 
      line = new GLine(x, y, x, y); 
      add(line); 
   } 
/** Called on mouse drag to reset the endpoint */ 
   public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { 
      double x = e.getX(); 
      double y = e.getY(); 
      line.setEndPoint(x, y); 
   } 

/* Private instance variables */ 
   private GLine line; 
}
```

Comment: Does that GraphicsProgram class implement runnable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first program only ever creates one `GLine`, which, because uninitialized `int` fields are initialized to zero, is always from (0,0) to (0,0).  On press events and drag events, it updates variables x1,y1, x2,y2 but never does anything with those values.

Every drag event adds another reference of `line` (the original (0,0)-(0,0) line) to the list/set of lines to be drawn.